# React Web app with a user login and headless CMS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, content-management-system, headless

So for an upcoming project I need to build a simple e-learning/training platform. As I am new to ReactJS I wanted to use that to build this web app. For this web app I want to use firebase for users to login and see the content and interact with it. Then I also need a CMS platform for the company to output data to the user.

I was curious what the best take would be for this project. Firstly build the base and user login and later on add the CMS or first the CMS and then the user login. Also looked at several headless CMS systems but not sure what would work best, especially with the firebase authentication.

Any help or directions would be great!